# git changing repository renaming

Tags: git

I am trying to rename the git repository, but I have trouble.

After, I changed the name, I reset the remote --

```
git remote set-url origin git@bitbucket.org:xxx/new_repo_name.git
```

But after that, I am getting error :

```
fatal: Could not chdir to '../../../original_repo_name': No such file or directory
```

What is the right way to do this? Thanks

Comment: The output of `git remote set-url` is that error?

Comment: Are you using `git worktree add`? Added worktrees have a special burden: once added, both the original repository *and* the added repository can only be moved if both are adjusted appropriately, since each one records the location of the other.